# When learning .net microservices, I got a DependencyInjection error

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, .net-7.0

Description:

I'm encountering an issue with dependency injection in my .NET Core 7.0 project. I have a ServicesController that depends on an IRepository, but I'm getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Marketmax.Common.IRepository`1[Marketmax.Service.Entities.ServiceEntity]' while attempting to activate 'Marketmax.MicroService.Controllers.ServicesController'.
```

I've tried various configurations, but I can't seem to resolve this issue. Here's a simplified version of my Startup.cs configuration:

```
// Configure services
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddMongo(configuration); // MongoDB setup
builder.Services.AddMongoRepository<ServiceEntity>("Services");

// Issue occurs here
builder.Services.AddScoped<ServicesController>();
```

And here's a snippet of my ServicesController:

```
namespace Marketmax.MicroService.Controllers
{
   [ApiController]
   [Route("services")]
   public class ServicesController : ControllerBase
   {
      private readonly IRepository<ServiceEntity> iRepository;

      public ServicesController(IRepository<ServiceEntity> repository)
      {
         this.iRepository = repository;
      }

      // ... (Controller actions)

   }
}
```

Additional Information:

I'm using .NET Core 7.0.
I have a MongoDB setup using the AddMongo and AddMongoRepository methods.
Ithink error occurs when trying to activate the ServicesController with the IRepository dependency.

This is a custom nuget package i added to the project:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IServiceEntity
{
    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync();

    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    Task CreateAsync(T entity);

    Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id);

    Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    Task RemoveAsync(Guid id);

    Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
}
```

Nuget Extension

```
public static class MongoExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMongo(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        IConfiguration configuration2 = configuration;
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
        BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new DateTimeSerializer(BsonType.String));
        services.AddSingleton(delegate
        {
            ServiceSettings serviceSettings = configuration2.GetSection("ServiceSettings").Get<ServiceSettings>();
            MongoDbSettings mongoDbSettings = configuration2.GetSection("MongoDbSettings").Get<MongoDbSettings>();
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoDbSettings.ConnectionString);
            return mongoClient.GetDatabase(serviceSettings.ServiceName);
        });
        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddMongoRepository<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string collectionName) where T : IServiceEntity
    {
        string collectionName2 = collectionName;
        services.AddSingleton((Func<IServiceProvider, IRepository<IServiceEntity>>)delegate (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IMongoDatabase service = serviceProvider.GetService<IMongoDatabase>();
            return new MongoRepository<IServiceEntity>(service, collectionName2);
        });
        return services;
    }
}
```

I followed this YouTube tutorial!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqCDOosvZIk&t=12364s

The Error message i got:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Marketmax.Common.IRepository`1[Marketmax.Service.Entities.ServiceEntity]' while attempting to activate 'Marketmax.MicroService.Controllers.ServicesController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method9(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Where's your implementation for `IRepository<ServiceEntity>`? You need to register it in your DI.

Comment: public interface IRepository<T> where T : IServiceEntity
{
    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync();

    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    Task CreateAsync(T entity);

    Task<T> GetAsync(Guid id);

    Task<T> GetAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    Task RemoveAsync(Guid id);

    Task UpdateAsync(T entity);
} this is a custom nuget package i added to the project!

Comment: Please [edit] your question for new information instead of adding it as comment.

Comment: _"this is a custom nuget package i added to the project!"_ - Look for an extension method on - probably - ServiceCollection. Maybe a `AddMarketMaxRepositories` or something like that. A _good_ library would make DI as easy for you as possible. If it doesn't have one and you have control over its source code, consider creating one.

Comment: What exactly does `AddMongoRepository<ServiceEntity>` register? Where does that extension come from?

Comment: Please review the edited question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `AddMongoRepository` method not resolving implementation of `IServiceEntity`. You need to register `ServiceEntity` as `IServiceEntity` before registering your controller.

Another problem with your `AddMongoRepository` method is that, it's not using provided generic type when registering new singleton, which means you'll get same service for all implementations of `IServiceEntity`.

To resolve this, you can modify your method as follows:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMongoRepository<T>(this IServiceCollection services, string collectionName) where T : IServiceEntity
    {
        string collectionName2 = collectionName;
        services.AddSingleton((Func<IServiceProvider, IRepository<T>>)delegate (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IMongoDatabase service = serviceProvider.GetService<IMongoDatabase>();
            return new MongoRepository<T>(service, collectionName2);
        });
        return services;
    }
```